# Weird cache folder containing a bunch of files

Tags: wordpress

Im trying to download my wordpress installation as a backup.
Its taking really long and i think this is mainly because of this weird files i have in my wordpress installation.

Located here:

[image]

In side there is this [image]

Inside the 00000 folder there is this:

[image]

Is this important? i do have the w3 total cache plugin installed (which im willing to delete if this solves the problem)

What are these files are they important ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to safely delete these as these are cache files made by w3 Total Cache.

Comment: awesome, ill give it a shot. I will let u know if it worked hold on